# Top 2 Months of Sales by Customer - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am trying to develop a query to pull out the top 2 months of sales by customer id. Here is a sample table:

```
Customer_ID   Sales Amount    Period 
144567         40               2
234567         50               5
234567         40               7
144567         80               10
144567         48               2
234567         23               7
```

desired output would be

```
Customer_ID  Sales Sum   Period
144567       80           10
144567       48            2
234567       50            5
234567       40            7
```

I've tried

```
select sum(net_sales_usd_spot), valid_period, customer_id
from sales_trans_price_output 
where valid_period in (select valid_period, sum(net_sales_usd_spot) 
                       from sales_trans_price_output 
                       where rank<=2)
group by valid_period, customer_id
```

error is

> too many values ORA-00913.

I see why, but not sure how to rework it.

Comment: **Do not** tag irrelevant DBMS please, SQL Server <> Oracle.

Comment: What relationship is there between "Period" in your table and "Months" in the title? Then: What is the significance of having two different rows for the same customer, with the same "Period" but different "Sales Amount"? Do those "Sales Amounts" (for the same period!!) have to be ADDED TOGETHER? Why does your "desired output" reflect only one of the two rows?

Comment: Period = months = format '201601' (for example). Period is the correct term. No, only sales amounts from different periods should be added together, e.g. Period 10 and Period 2 sales for 144567. Not sure I understand the last question.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by sales_amount desc ) rn
  FROM sales_trans_price t
)
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY 1,2 desc
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/882888/3

Comment: Windowing functions ftw. Ignore my garbage below.

Comment: I think I got it: SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, valid_period,
         row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by sum(net_sales_usd_spot) desc ) rn
  FROM sales_trans_price_output
  group by customer_id, valid_period
)
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY 1,2 desc

Answer (score 1):

what if you change your where clause to:

```
where valid_period in
(
select p.valid_period from sales_trans_price_output p
join (select valid_period, sum(net_sales_usd_spot) 
                   from sales_trans_price_output 
                   where rank<=2) s on s.valid_period = p.valid_period
)
```

It might be ugly and need refactoring, but I think this is the logic you're after.

Comment: It is ugly but someone had to get your reputation into 3 digits.  You owe me a beer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of this.

```
where valid_period in (select valid_period, sum(net_sales_usd_spot) 
                       from sales_trans_price_output 
                       where rank<=2)
```

The subquery can only contain one field.

You are on the right track using `rank`, but you might not be using it correctly.  Google `oracle rank` to find the correct syntax.

Back to what you are looking to achieve, a derived table is the approach I would use.  That's simply a subquery with an alias.  Or, if you use the keyword `with`, it might be called a CTE - Computed Table Expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT * FROM  (
      SELECT T.*,
             RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID 
                           ORDER BY VALID_PERIOD DESC) FN_RANK
      FROM SALES_TRANS_PRICE_OUTPUT  T
      ) A
WHERE A.FN_RANK <= 2
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID ASC, VALID_PERIOD DESC, FN_RANK DESC
```

Comment: That's ordering by period and not by sum(sales). But otherwise it works.